# MS Bluetooth stack documentation

Tags: c++, c, windows, bluetooth

I want to develop a Bluetooth application for Windows 7. Where could I find a proper documentation, tutorials and so on? My intention is to use Microsoft stack.

The MSDN is sterile about this topic, in the sense that they have a long list of Windows API functions for Bluetooth with brief descriptions, but with no logical start and end. Until now the best valuable resource found by me is a web tutorial:

http://www.winsocketdotnetworkprogramming.com/winsock2programming/winsock2advancedotherprotocol4j.html

Any other ideas?

Thnx

Answer (score 3):

If you want some examples of the MS stack in action, check out the source for the [BlueCove](http://bluecove.org/) project.  It's a complete implementation of [JSR-82](http://download.oracle.com/javame/config/cldc/opt-pkgs/api/bluetooth/jsr082/index.html) (the Java BT interface) written to use a variety of stacks, including MS.  For example, [this file](http://code.google.com/p/bluecove/source/browse/trunk/bluecove/src/main/c/intelbth/intelbth.cpp) exercises lots of the stack.

Comment: Thnx is real interesting, I've found good C/C++ samples there.

Answer (score 2):

The first two results in bing (no, seriously!) for "msdn bluetooth" are [Bluetooth (Windows)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa362932%28VS.85%29.aspx) and [Bluetooth (Windows CE .NET 4.2)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms863414.aspx) and those are good entry-points to programming on Windows desktop and CE/WM respectively.  Lots of good stuff there.

Of course I'd recommend managed code and my managed library for Bluetooth, OBEX, etc: [32feet.NET](http://32feet.codeplex.com) :-)

Comment: Alan I know your library and it is a good one, actually it is a .net wrapper over native API. I would've used it but this time I need something native. Anyway thnx for the Windows CE.Net 4.2 it seems that there are pretty good samples there.

Answer (score 0):

Well, reference is [here on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa362930%28v=VS.85%29.aspx) at the moment.

Comment: That's the official starting point indeed, I would add the Windows DDK MSDN page for Bluetooth: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff536768%28v=VS.85%29.aspx