# Interaction between Bluetooth and a computer

Tags: c++, mfc, bluetooth

I'm developing a device and writing the software for it under Windows (MFC with Visual Studio).

I would like to start a measurement with a remote. It would be nice if it worked over [Bluetooth](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bluetooth), but I don't have a clue where to start.

What book can recommended or is there a site where such things are described?

Is it even possible to make my own Bluetooth device or do I have to pay some fee for licences?

What I would like to have, is a Bluetooth-remote with one button, which sends a signal to a Windows PC where a program then starts specific subroutines.

Comment: The msdn is always a good place to start.  <http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa362932%28v=vs.85%29.aspx>  Maybe someone else would know about good books or hardware though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As Dan wrote in the comment when it comes to Microsoft the best place to start is with MSDN. For me his link didn't work, but I guess he wanted to point [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa362932(v=VS.85).aspx).

MFC does not offer you support for Bluetooth, instead you have to work with a Bluetooth driver stack API. On Windows there are more stacks, but most widely used are: [Microsoft Bluetooth driver stack](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bluetooth_stack#Microsoft_Windows_stack) and [Widcomm/Broadcom](http://www.broadcom.com/support/bluetooth/sdk.php). If you decide to use the Microsoft Bluetooth driver stack you might want to look on this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4707654/ms-bluetooth-stack-documentation). The stack that you choose it depends on the Bluetooth dongle attached/incorporated at your PC.

> Is it even possible to make my own Bluetooth device or do I have to pay some fee for licences?

Yes, it is possible to make your own Bluetooth device. The fee depends from case to case, first if you want to be assigned your own IDs from SIG you have to pay them a fee, otherwise you can use the ones already bought by the chip manufacturer. Also if you want to re-write the firmware from the chip you could be forced to buy a software from the chip manufacturer. Usually it's enough with their firmware.

> What I would like to have, is a Bluetooth-remote with one button, which sends a signal to a Windows PC where a Software then starts specific subroutines.

Well, it seems you will have to take care of the device discovery aspect and second make the pairing. After this you could use Serial Port Profile to communicate with your device like any other RS-232 enabled device. If your device is dedicated you might want to modify the IAC - Inquiry Access Code so in discovery phase only you that you know the code, can see the device.